# inline elements printing on new line

Tags: css, printing, printing-web-page

I have the following code:

```
<div class="outsideDiv">
    <div class="element1">Name: </div>
    <div class="element2">Something</div>
    <div class="element3"> - </div>
    <div class="element4">This something is great</div>
</div>
```

The outer div is display:block and all of the inside divs are display:inline.  In the browser it all shows up on the same line like this:

```
Name: Something - This something is great
```

When I go to print it, the 4 divs show up on seperate lines like this:

```
Name: 
Something
-
This something is great
```

I am having a hard time figuring out how to get the 4 inside divs to print on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="outsideDiv">
    <div class="element1" style="display:inline">Name: </div>
    <div class="element2" style="display:inline">Something</div>
    <div class="element3" style="display:inline"> - </div>
    <div class="element4" style="display:inline">This something is great</div>
</div>
```

or

write this to your print.css:

```
.element1,.element2, .element3, .element4 {display: inline;}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using print.css and not putting the styles in the html code?

Comment: Write this into your print.css: .element1, .element2,.element3,.element4 {display:inline;}